# Creating a Gmail add-on with input prefix functionality similar to Bootstrap

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace, add-on

I am working on developing a Gmail add-on using Google Apps Script and I'm trying to achieve a similar functionality to what Bootstrap provides with its input group and prefix functionality. Specifically, I want to add a prefix (icon or text) to an input field within the Gmail add-on.

In Bootstrap, I can achieve this with the following code:

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

I want to replicate this kind of prefix functionality in a Gmail add-on, where users can see a symbol or text before the input field, and the input field resizes accordingly.
For reference, here's the functionality I'm aiming for, as seen in Google Sheets: (https://prnt.sc/u4cLB1DT4uNs).
Below is the code for simple **text input** in **card service**.

Code. gs

```
let widget = CardService.newTextInput().setTitle("Currency")

return CardService.newCardBuilder().addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(widget)).build()
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve this kind of input prefix functionality within a Gmail add-on using Google Apps Script?
2. If yes, what would be the general approach to implement this? Are there any specific methods or components provided by Google Apps Script that I can use for creating input prefixes in a Gmail add-on?
3. Are there any limitations or considerations I should be aware of when implementing such a feature in a Gmail add-on?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, code examples, or guidance that the community can provide.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to use the Bootstrap functionality in apps script.
You can still use Bootstrap as is the same way it is being added to the html code by adding the **Bootstrap cdn** in apps script, in your .html.
Otherwise you would have to style it manually like in html using the  tag.

### Sample below:

[image]

[image]

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this helps or if you have other questions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I want to implement this functionality in Gmail Addon using card service. 
Can you please write the code for card services?

Comment: Hi and welcome. The goal of StackOverflow is to help users solve their problems by pointing them to the right direction, giving insights and helping with what you have already worked on, but it is not a bespoke coding service. You have to decide whether your problem is your lack of coding skills, in which case you need to work on that (here's the place to start), OR whether your problem is that the code that you have written or researched is not meeting your needs. In both cases, I think you have some work to do, and you can edit your question when you have a more specific problem to resolve.

Comment: If you have already existing code that you need help on you may post that as another question. If this post answers the question then feel free to accept the answer, if this somehow helps you may also upvote. @ShivYadav

Comment: Actually, I'm not getting where I have to start the coding and I don't have any existing code so, that's what I had asked for code. can you add an image of the card service code?